# What's the meaning of "not just"?

Tags: meaning

## Could you please tell me what the meaning of "**not just**" here is?

> I certainly didn’t
>   sound like them, and not just because they were British. Their speech had a lilting cadence that made me think of singing more than speaking.
>   *Educated* by Tara Westover

---

I find in two online dictionaries the meanings below for "not just":

- used to say that one thing is true and that another thing is also true.

**EX**: She's not just my friend, she's my lawyer. [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not%20just)

- not only

**EX**: It’s not just me. Other people are complaining too. [2](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/not-just)

but I don't know for certain if they fit with the phrase or not. Does it simply mean?

> > I certainly didn’t sound like them, because:
>
> (1)they were British
>
> [moreover] (2)their speech had a lilting cadence that made me think of singing
>
> > more than speaking.

Could you help me please to find  an exact answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dressed in dark colors for my first lecture, hoping I wouldn’t stand out, but even so I didn’t think I looked like the other students. I certainly didn’t sound like them, and not **just because** they were British. Their speech had a lilting cadence that made me think of singing more than speaking. To my ears they sounded refined, educated; I had a tendency to mumble, and when nervous, to stutter.

Means:

> I didn't sound like them but I **can't** say that **the only reason** why I didn't sound like them is that they were British. **In addition to this reason**, Their speech had a lilting cadence that made me think of singing more than speaking. To my ears they sounded refined, educated; I had a tendency to mumble, and when nervous, to stutter.

An example,

> I didn't like him but **not just because** he was rude. He was **also** uneducated.

Means:

> I didn't like him because he was **both** rude and uneducated.